# Can repositories be used in domain services?

Tags: javascript, service, architecture, repository, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to implement my first domain driven application, after going through Eric Evan's book on Domain-Driven Design. I'm a bit confused on how to go about creating Value Objects.

So in my application, a user can purchase a service for getting them certain number of views on a video they post in Youtube, which is fulfilled by the other users of my app who watch those videos, the incentive being they'll earn coins(in app currency) for every video they watch, which they in turn can use to promote their videos(Basically a replica of the many youtube promoter apps already available, for learning).

Say the service is represented in the app as an entity called WatchTime. The WatchTime entity contains some information like the Video URL, MaxViews(max number of views purchased) and CurrentViews(number of views already fulfilled), etc and also a rank. This rank determines how frequently the rank should be displayed.

When a user opens the page to watch videos to earn coins, the app should get N number of WatchTimes, say 10, and once the user has completed watching them, the next batch of N WatchTimes will be loaded in. The 10 watchtimes to be loaded in is decided based on the rank of the watchTimes.

Now for the question. The algorithm for selecting the videos based on their rank to play will be a business thing ig, so ig the service that gets the watchtimes from the repository would be in the domain. But I've read that the repository shouldn't be used in the domain, but the service wouldn't be able to check the rank of a watchtime and return itwithout the accessing the repository. So how would I go about doing this?

Also feel free to tell me I'm wrong if said anything dumb and please explain why. And if anything I said isn't clear please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens with the watch times that are loaded? Will the UI just ask for the next videos and play them? Will there be validation on the backend to make sure the watched videos were the ones expected according to their rank? If it's just a simple query then you'd just have `watchTimesRepository.nextToWatchFor(user)` or something like that and it's the application layer that would call upon the repository (which IS a domain service).

Comment: @plalx ill need to get watchTimes based on their rank, so i figured the algorithm for picking which watchtime to get from my database would be part of the domain. But ive heard using repository in domain service is a nono

Comment: Well, ordering by rank is a rather simple query. As long as the domain is responsible for ranking your can use the repository for ordering by rank. What do you do with these watch times ARs once they are loaded?

Answer (score 2):

The domain service should perform business logic that aggregates, entities or value objects are not capable of, therefore I would avoid using repositories in them as much as possible.

In your case, instead of using the repository to obtain a specific data, you should use the repository to obtain an aggregate that contains that information, and pass that aggregate to the domain service so that it performs the business logic that it is not capable of perform the addition yourself.